# How to add a confirmed O365 domain as an Exchange Online accepted domain?

Tags: email, azure, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

A little background on our AAD/O35 tenancy:

- We have domainA as our primary domain. This is used for SSO, our primary email addresses, etc etc.
- We acquired another business.
  One of their domains (domainB) was listed in the previous parent company's
  AAD/O365 tenancy.  The previous owner removed it from their AAD/O365 tenancy, freeing it up for us.
- We ran through the O365 "Add Domain", and set it up for Exchange Online.  We updated our public DNS records, and it shows a nice green check-mark (Healthy!).
- When viewing domainB in our tenancy, we see MX, TXT and CNAME records all have status OK.

However, when we go into our Exchange Online admin portal, it is not listed as an Accepted Domain.

We waited several days just to make sure there wasn't a delay on Microsoft's end, which has been known to happen.

In the olden-days, the "classic" Exchange Online control panel had an option to manually add an Accepted Domain.  That functionality has been removed; the process is now to run through the Add Domain wizard.. which reports everything is good, but we do not see domainB listed in our Accepted Domains for Exchange Online.

Exchange Shell can handle this with **New-AcceptedDomain** for on-prem Exchange; but that command does not exist for Exchange Online.

Anyone with any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this domain has been verified in your Office 365 tenant then open a support case from your tenant. Office 365 support is always free. Don't waste time searching for a solution. The quickest way to get this resolved is via Office 365 support.

Comment: @joeqwerty we ended up putting in a ticket with MS.  Their support staff said that they needed to do a "resync" and it was likely related to the domain being associated with a previous tenant.  Everything is working correctly, now.  Thanks!